# Can't start a Elixir Phoenix as a mix release

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm not able to start my project from a `mix release`. But it works fine if I run `mix phx.server`

I'm able to recreate this problem from an empty project by doing:

`mix phx.new asdf --umbrella --no-ecto --no-html --no-webpack`

then edit `mix.exs` and add a release section:

```erlang
def project do
    [
      apps_path: "apps",
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      deps: deps(),
      version: "0.1.0",
      releases: [
        mega_umbrella: [
          applications: [
            mega: :permanent,
            mega_web: :permanent
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  end
```

then remove the last line from `config/prod.exs`

`# import_config "prod.secret.exs`

run `mix release`

run `_build/dev/rel/asdf_umbrella/bin/asdf_umbrella start`

And the application just hangs there.

What am I doing wrong and why is it just hanging there?

My version info:

```
elixir --version
Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.5.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe] [dtrace]

Elixir 1.9.2 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 22)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all when it comes to configs, in new releases of distillery there is a new feature, called runtime configs, witch are favored instead of the ones at compile time, you can read more about them [here](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Release.html#module-runtime-configuration).

The basic idea behind this feature is that you can fetch environment variables when the server is run, when compared to the old config you had to provide all the configuration at build time, this comes really handy when working with containers and in general is more flexible.

The steps for making runtime config are the following:

1. Inside `config` folder create `releases.exs` file;
2. Copy all the config you have provided in `prod.exs` or at least the parts you want to override;
3. Use `System.fetch_env!\1` to get the data from environment variables;

You should remember that runtime config overrides the previous config, so if for example you provide `prod.exs` config at compile time, everything new in `releases.exs` will override the old config.

An example of a part of such config is:

```
config :tachocard_api, TachocardApi.Repo,
       username: System.fetch_env!("PGUSER"),
       password: System.fetch_env!("PGPASSWORD"),
       database: System.fetch_env!("PGDATABASE"),
       hostname: System.fetch_env!("PGHOST"),
       pool_size: 10
```

Then in your deploy environment you set those environment variables to the values you need. `System.fetch_env!/1` bang version is recommended, since it will throw an error if the environment variable is not set.

Comment: How can you make the environment variables available in the server? in `.bashrc`? Maybe in `/etc/systemd/system/yourapp.service`?

Comment: it depends, usually you have a dockerized solution where you can set your environment variables before starting the server.

Comment: Where exactly do you put your database env vars, assuming you'll be running your app via systemd?