# Elixir config files in elixir 1.9?

Tags: elixir, config

Just curious since the config has been removed from elixir 1.9. I don't fully understand the preferred method of loading config files in Elixir.  For development, should I still create a config/config.exs?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you use mix, the configs are the same, this means that in development phase you still can use the old configs.

The changes were introduced when deploying with distillery. Instead of compile-time config, a runtime config was added.

This has the advantage that each time when server is restarted, you can generate a new config based on some variables (usually environment).

You can still use your old configs, however you will shortly find out that a runtime config is much more powerful. You can read a detailed explanation in one of my [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58816356/8103819).

Comment: Well, they were introduced because of the new preferred way of building releases ([`mix release`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Release.html#content),) not because of distillery. Also, `Mix.Config` does not require `mix` in runtime, so your item 2 is confusing.

Comment: yeah my bad, I've read something about the fact that you cannot use mix after release.