# Reading ubuntu environment variables in elixir production app

Tags: elixir

I'm unable to get my application to read an environment variable set on Ubuntu. I keep getting the message below:

`** (ArgumentError) could not fetch environment variable "VARIABLE" because it is not set`

This is what I have in my prod.exs
    `variable: System.get_env("VARIABLE") || "${VARIABLE}"`

I then try to run my application as below

`RELX_REPLACE_OS_VARS=true /home/app/prod/rel/my_app/bin/my_app start`

I've looked everywhere but tutorials either seem mostly to lean towards Phoenix which I do not have in my application or using an additional dependency which I am not too inclined to do.

Comment: this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58815793/cant-start-a-elixir-phoenix-as-a-mix-release/58816356#58816356

Comment: No joy! I'd tried this ealier. I get the error below:

`{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{'Elixir.System','get_env!',[<<"VARIABLE">>],[]},{erl_eval,do_apply,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,680}]}`

Comment: that should work for sure, check your elixir version, runtime configs are available since 1.9

Comment: I'm not familiar with `RELX_REPLACE_OS_VARS`, but have you tried something as simple as setting the ENV var when you run the command? E.g. `VARIABLE=something /home/app/prod/rel/my_app/bin/my_app start` ?   It sounds like you could be running into the problems with trying to read ENVs at _runtime_ when they were read (and persisted) at _compile-time_.

Comment: if you have a runtime configuration, the compile-time one gets overwritten.

Comment: Which version of elixir ar you using? Are you using distillery? In which file are you reading the variable?

Comment: I'm using elixir version 1.9.2. I've since removed these lines `RELX_REPLACE_OS_VARS=true` and trying to use mix releases. The environment variable can be seen when you `printenv` but not replaced at start as documentation says of anything placed in `releases.exs`